# CSS: Make the width of auto div to expand till positioned element

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem. 

How to make a div expand till the end of the positioned element.

```css
.apple {
  background: #ccc;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="apple">
  A for aplle
  <br><a style="position:relative; top:20px;">B for Ball</a>
</div>
```

Here, the div doesn't accept the width of the position changed element. How to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Either use `margin` or `padding` instead the top position.

Comment: @DaniP  Thanks for your reply. This is actually a simplified version. I cannot use margin/padding over there.

Comment: interesting, can you replicate the more complex situation ?

Comment: remove top:20px... or <div class="apple" style="padding-bottom:20px">

Answer (score 2):

Its doing what it should.  You are positioning the element 20px below where it naturally falls in the DOM, so it is placed outside the gray div.  I understand your situation may be more complicated.  Can you do something like add `padding-bottom:20px`?

```css
.apple {
  background: #ccc;
  width: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="apple">
  A for aplle
  <br><a style="position:relative; top:20px;">B for Ball</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display: table;` to the parent and `display: table-row;` to the child.

```css
.apple {
  background: #ccc;
  width: auto;
  display: table;
}
.apple a {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="apple">
  A for aplle
  <br><a style="position:relative; top:20px;">B for Ball</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative` moves the element away from its original position (if there are top, bottom, right or left settings), but still reserves the space it originally had, at its original (non-moved) position, which you see in your example. It does NOT change the dimensions of the parent element as opposed to `static` positioning.

To solve the issue, you can make the `a` tag an `inline-block`, erase the relative positioning and use `margin-top` instead of `top`. This will be wrapped by the parent:

```css
.apple {
  background: #ccc;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="apple">
  A for aplle
  <br><a style="display: inline-block; margin-top:20px;">B for Ball</a>
</div>
```